# DataGridRow Background-color is dropping to default after sorting

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

my problem is:
In my WPF-application I have *standart DataGrid* and *ColorPicker from Extended WPF Toolkit*. The task is to change background color of DataGridRow when user select a new color in ColorPicker. I made it with next code:

```
private void ColorPicker_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
        {
            DataGridRow[] selectedDataGridRows = new DataGridRow[DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                selectedDataGridRows[i] = (DataGridRow)DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DataGrid1.SelectedItems[i]);
                Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(e.NewValue)));
                selectedDataGridRows[i].Style = style;
            }
        }
```

It works well and background of DataGridRow changes, BUT after sorting or scrolling DataGrid all chosen background colors drop to default (white).
I don`t know why it happens and ask for help. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571178/why-datagrid-selected-row-background-changes-after-sort) I find useful information, but I can use this method only in XAML ... Maybe there is a way to change *InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey* in С#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `DataGrid` uses virtualization to improve performance - it instantiates `DataGridRow` only for the currently visible items of the `ItemsSource` and it creates (or recycles) more as necessary (e.g. when users resizes the window or scrolls).

To fix your immediate problem you can do something like this:

```
public UserControl1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    DataGrid1.LoadingRow += DataGrid1_LoadingRow;
}

Dictionary<int, Style> rowStyles = new Dictionary<int, Style>();

void DataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = DataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(e.Row.Item);
    if (rowStyles.ContainsKey(rowIndex))
    {
        e.Row.Style = rowStyles[rowIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Style = null;
    }
}

void ColorPicker_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
{
    Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(e.NewValue)));
    foreach (object selectedItem in DataGrid1.SelectedItems)
    {
        int rowIndex = DataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
        rowStyles[rowIndex] = style;
    }
    DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
}
```

However, I would recommend reading up on MVVM and dynamic styling in WPF and instead of modifying the view directly bind the view to model and modify the model only:

1. Extend your data model to contain new style property
2. Bind DataGridRow.Style to the model's style property
3. When user picks a color, modify appropriate model style

For example:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding rowBackground}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>

DataTable Model { get; set; }

public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Model = new DataTable() { Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture };
    this.Model.Columns.Add("a", typeof(int));
    this.Model.Columns.Add("b", typeof(string));
    this.Model.Columns.Add("rowBackground", typeof(Brush));
    this.Model.Rows.Add(1, "one", Brushes.White);
    this.Model.Rows.Add(2, "two", Brushes.White);
    this.Model.Rows.Add(3, "three", Brushes.White);
    this.Model.AcceptChanges();

    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = this.Model.DefaultView;
}

void ColorPicker_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
{
    Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(e.NewValue);
    foreach (DataRowView selectedItem in DataGrid1.SelectedItems)
    {
        selectedItem["rowBackground"] = brush;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Dusan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400470/dusan), thanks a lot. First solution works, but not well - after sorting indexes move and color of row with index 1 moves to first row in table (it may be 11 row or 5 row - depends on sorting result). But second solution works wery fine, and ideal suit to architecture of my application. I think it`s my time to learn MVVM pattern :)